# Point rviz to new roscore?

Tags: rviz, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Neil Traft pointed out in his question [RViz won't refresh my TF tree](http://answers.ros.org/question/189762), You need to restart RViz whenever you start a new roscore. RViz looks for a roscore upon startup. After that time, the roscore remains fixed.

Is it somehow possible to point rviz to a new roscore if the one it found on startup doesn't exist anymore?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259423/point-rviz-to-new-roscore?/) by [lalten](https://answers.ros.org/users/25550/lalten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2017-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No; this is a general issue with roscpp, and you cannot change the roscore that roscpp is using once it is started.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0